# Deploy VB.NET to other machines, with localhost as Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

is it possible to deploy my VB.NET application to other machine if it's database is my PC's localhost, example: MainMachine(where i developed my application and contains my database) and i want to deploy my application to ClientMachine(where my application should be deployed) but the problem is my application cannot detect any database when i deploy it to ClientMachine, what seem to be the problem here?
Sorry for my bad english.
thank you in advance for answers

Comment: You need to specify the correct address (your pc) of your database in your connection string. See this [MySql Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: well actually my connection string is correct, my problem is when i deploy my application on other machine it does not recognize my set database on the application, and im thinking the main problem is because i used localhost of the MainMachine as my database

Comment: Show us your connection string (without username and password) that you are using on the new host

Comment: i'm using the standard connection string

Comment: Show us your connection string

Comment: Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=mypassword;

Comment: On the other machine where you deployed your app, you need to change the connection string to point to your dev machine where the database is located.  Change localhost to the correct machine name where the database is installed.

Comment: i want to deploy my application to other machine with it's database, how to do that?